# Best practice for sharing photos to my service

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

Imagine a service which is called "Add a cat or a dog to that" (https://developers.google.com/glass/stories)

What is the best practice to do that:

- Add two contact "Add a cat to that" or "Add a dog to that" to the
  user
- Add one concat and when a user share a photo with this contact,
  insert a new item in the timeline and asking to choose between adding
  a dog or a cat to this photo

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We recommend this one:

> Add two contact "Add a cat to that" or "Add a dog to that" to the user

There are a few reasons for this:

- Your user can manage these contacts independently. This means if they only ever want to insert dogs, they can chose to only enable that Contact.
- The flow requires fewer network round trips to complete, and we all love snappy software, right?
- If the user misses the card you mention in the 2nd option, the flow will stall out only half complete. You should never depend on your users seeing every timeline card you insert.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would add two contacts. It seems more intuitive from a UX perspective.

Comment: I agree. But maybe there is a risk of " contact overload" where services create too many contacts (one for each use case) ? It could be spammy

Comment: It could get spammy, but if I am not mistaken the user can set priority to contacts. I imagine that this will naturally evolve in the coming months. It is a similar issue with apps on an iPhone. You have lots of apps and sometimes forget where they are. Good thing you can use siri or search to easily locate them and use them.